# Get sample set from large dataset

Tags: c#, linq

I have an in memory dataset that I'm trying to get an evenly distributed sample using LINQ.  From what I've seen, there isn't anything that does this out of the box, so I'm trying to come up with some kind of composition or extension that will perform the sampling.

What I'm hoping for is something that I can use like this:

```
var sample = dataset.Sample(100);
var smallSample = smallDataset.Sample(100);

Assert.IsTrue(dataset.Count() > 100);
Assert.IsTrue(sample.Count() == 100);

Assert.IsTrue(smallDataset.Count() < 100);
Assert.IsTrue(smallSample .Count() == smallDataset.Count());
```

The composition I started with, but only works some of the time is this:

```
var sample = dataset
             .Select((v,i) => new Tuple<string, int>(v,i))
             .Where(t => t.Item2 / (double)(dataset.Count() / SampleSize) % 1 != 0)
             .Select(t => t.Item1);
```

This works when the dataset and the sample size share a common devisor and the sample size is greater than 50% of the dataset size.  Or something like that.

Any help would be excellent!

**Update:** So I have the following *non*-LINQ logic that works, but I'm trying to figure out if this can be "LINQ'd" somehow.

```
var sample = new List<T>();
double sampleRatio = dataset.Count() / sampleSize;

for (var i = 0; i < dataset.Count(); i++)
{
    if ((sample.Count() * sampleRatio) <= i) 
        sample.Add(dataset.Skip(i).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Would a random ordering and then a `Take(SampleSize)` work for your purposes, or do you need a uniform sampling?  Also I'd try to handle the case where sample size is larger than the collection outside of Linq.

Comment: I was thinking about that, but this is for a timeline visualization, and random distribution might not look right.

Comment: I don't think your algorithm is correct.  The x-axis is evenly spaced which is not statistically correct.  If you were a cashier at a store it would be like a person checking out every minute with each person spending a different amount of money.  What you really want is people randomly checking out and each person spending random amount of money.

Comment: @jdweng  Actually, the algorithm is correct, in that it does what I want it to do (evenly distribute data along the x-axis).  You are correct that this could mask important data if the data was random numerical data.  This specific data, however, is log information.  At a general level, if a specific entry type reoccurs frequently, it would be logged more, and it would have a greater chance of showing up on the dashboard.  When I search for a 10 minute windows in these logs, we could have thousands of entries, and I just want to take an evenly distributed sample that can be drilled into later.

Comment: Have you tried using the LINQ Take operator?

Comment: Simulation data should always represent actual data.  If your actual data is sampled at fixed intervals than your simulation is correct.

Comment: Also check out the `TakeWhile()` method or just `Where()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find a satisfactory LINQ solution, mainly because iterating LINQ statements are not aware of the length of the sequence they work on -- which is OK: it totally fits LINQ's deferred-execution and streaming approach. Of course it's possible to store the length in a variable and use this in a `Where` statement, but that's not in line with LINQ's functional (stateless) paradigm, so I always try to avoid that.

The `Aggregate` statement can be stateless and length-aware, but I tend to find solutions using `Aggregate` rather contrived and hard to read. It's nothing but a covert stateful loop; `for` and `foreach` take some more lines, but are far easier to follow.

I can offer you an extension method that does what you want:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> TakeProrated<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, int numberOfItems)
{
    var local = sequence.ToList();
    var n = Math.Min(local.Count, numberOfItems);
    var dist = (decimal)local.Count / n;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        var index = (int)(Math.Ceiling(i * dist));
        yield return local[index];
    }
}
```

The idea is that the required distance between items is first calculated. Then the requested number of items is returned, each time roughly skipping this distance, sometimes more, sometimes less, but evenly distributed. Using `Math.Ceiling` or `Math.Floor` is arbitrary, they either introduce a bias toward items higher in the sequence, or lower.

Comment: Yep, I figured that pure LINQ composition wasn't going to cut this one since it required knowledge from previous iterations be passed up the chain.  Thanks for the extension method!  It appears to work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're looking for. From what I understand, you're looking to return only a certain quantity of entities in a dataset. As my comment to your original post asks, have you tried using the Take operator? What you're looking for is something like this.

```
// .Skip is optional, but you can use it with it.
// Just ensure that instead of .FirstOrDefault(), you use Take(quantity)
var sample = dataSet.Skip(amt).Take(dataSet.Count() / desiredSampleSize);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm looking for _evenly distributed_ samples. For example, if I want to take 5 samples from the range of 1-10, I would want the return to be either {1,3,5,7,9} or {2,4,6,8,10}. Your suggestion would return {1,2}, since 10/5 = 2

Comment: Oh, then you'd have to write your own LINQ operator there. As far as I'm aware, even doing the non-operator version of LINQ won't accomplish what you're looking for. Do a for loop with the iterator incrementing by Y every time, with X being defined. Only way you'll be able to do it.